# How to read the value within a button via Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am working on a script that aims "taking all of the entries which are written by users" under a specific title in a website(In this case, the title is "python(programlama dili"). I would like to read the number which shows the current number of pages under this specific title.

[image: the-number-I-want-to-read]

The reason behind reading the number of this elements is that number of pages can increase at the time when we run the script due to increasing number of entries by users. Thus, I should take the number which exist within the element via script.

In this case, I need to read "122" as the value and assign it to a int variable . I use Selenium to take all entries and Firefox web driver.

Answer (score 0):

First pick the selector `.last` and then you can extract the reference of that. Don't forget to split the reference.

```
my_val = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".last [href]").split("p=")[1]
```

Comment: My script needs to take the value of number of the pages automatically. I mean, the value which is 122 can increase in further days. So, Script needs to read the current number. If I copy the css path, I will contain the latest number in the item. However, it can change in further days. Did I explain it clearly? If not, I can explain it again.

Comment: My snippet takes the current value from the link reference. If the website will updated, you have to run your script again, and this time the script will detect the new value.

Answer (score 0):

It Would be better if you try to access it using the xpath.

Comment: I can find the button via xpath. However, how can I get the value (which is number in this case) within the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try and get the value attribute of the element, you've mentioned you can find the element using xpath so you can do the following.

```
user_count = element.get_attribute('value')
```

If that gets you the number (as a string) then you can just convert to an int as usual

```
value = int(user_count)
```